# Show that the curve x = 5 cos t, y = 4 sin t cos t has two tangents at (0, 0) and find their equations.

Tags: calculus

1) As x = 5cos(t); differentiating, dx/dt = - 5sin(t)

2) As y = 4sin(t)cos(t), y = 2sin(2t) [Since 2sin(t)cos(t) = sin(2t)] 
==> dy/dt = 4cos(2t)

3) So, dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt) = 4cos(2t)/-5sin(t) = -(4/5)[cos(2t)/sin(t)]

4), At x = 0, cos(t) = 0; ==> t = either pi/2 or 3pi/2 
As well y = 0, we get t = 0, pi/2, pi, 3pi/2, 2pi 
Intersection of both = {pi/2, 3pi/2}

5) By geometrical definition of differentiation, dy/dx is the slope of the tangent at a given point on the curve. Since here for x = 0, there are two values of t,corresponding to which, we get two slopes. Hence there are two tangents at the given point (0,0). 
The two slopes are: 
At (t = pi/2): dy/dx = (-4/5)[cos(pi)/sin(pi/2)] = (-4/5)[-1/1] = 4/5 
At (t = 3pi/2): dy/dx = (-4/5)[cos(3pi)/sin(3pi/2)] = (-4/5)[-1/-1] = -4/5

6) Equations of tangents: At (0,0)

i) Slope = -4/5 (Smaller slope): 
==> y - 0 = (-4/5)(x - 0) 
==> y = -4x/5 
==> 4x + 5y = 0.

ii) Slope = 4/5 {Larger slope):

Proceeding as above, 4x - 5y = 0

The two tangents are: "4x + 5y = 0; and 4x - 5y = 0"

Yet, My answer is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.
The graph looks like this.

[image]

Comment: How come the program I am using is stating it is wrong?

Comment: In the title, you had written y = 6 sin t cos t, but in the body you used y = 4 sin t cos t. So I suggested to edit the one in the title. Maybe you mixed those two also in your program..?

Comment: No the title is correct. I made a mistake with the body.  I will try to crunch the numbers again. Sorry.